# Unclear about import method

Tags: python, import

I need to use some online code and I am not sure about some import methods used. Here is the top part of the code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function

import itertools
import multiprocessing
import sys
import time
import warnings

import numpy as np

ot = True
try:
    from ot.lp import emd_c, check_result
    from scipy.spatial.distance import _distance_wrap # ot imports scipy anyway
except:
    warnings.warn('cannot import module \'ot\', module \'emd\' will be empty')
    ot = False
```

What is that `ot.lp`? As far as I can tell it would look like `True.lp` but I have never seen this before (I am not even sure what to google for). Also I am always getting the error, and I have no idea what should I do to fix it. Thank you!

Comment: Where did you find this?

Comment: Prob this one https://pot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/ot/lp.html the ot in your text is not substituted by true

Comment: It seems like just an unpleasant way of having a flag, `ot`, that starts of as `True`, but if the import from `ot.lp` fails, is set to `False`. Presumably later on there's some more code that depends on having successfully imported the earth-mover's distance stuff. Intuitively, it does seem like trying to import from `ot.lp` after assigning `True` to `ot` would not work, but apparently it does. It would be better to call `ot` something like `has_ot`, say. See also @gmds's very good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ot.lp is a [python optimal transport module](https://pot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/ot/lp.html). Link to source code is attached.

Comment: I feel so dumb now... Thanks a lot for this! However, how come there is no problem with using the same name for a package and a variable?

Comment: It's probable some would advise against this, but Python knows that once you write **from ... import ....** you're referring to a package and not a variable and therefore doesn't conflate the two. Also, never feel dumb.........

Answer (score 3):

Here, unfortunately, `ot` means two things: the name for a `bool` variable, *and* a module (which others have linked to).

The intention of the code is to have the *variable* `ot` be `True` if the *module* `ot` can be imported, and `False` otherwise. Therefore, presumably, elsewhere in the code checks against the value of the variable `ot` are done.

This, in and of itself, is not bad practice, but the variable name could be improved, at least.

When you use a name in an `import` statement, Python will look for that name in the directories specified in the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable and *ignore* similar names that are defined in code. So, for example, this works:

```
sklearn = None

from sklearn import linear_model
```

You can see that Python does not resolve the variable `sklearn` to attempt to import `linear_model` from `None`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that library is called [POT: Python Optimal Transport](https://pot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html). You can install it with:

```
pip install POT
```